# Application_BeginRequest not being fired in stressed environment

Tags: asp.net

We are obesrving strange problems when performing sress test of our applciation. We use Application_BeginRequest and Application_EndRequest to log the beginning and end of the web request, together, with the thread id.

However, from our logs, we see that Application_Begin_REquest is not being fired:

We use the following code to do the logging in global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string url = "";
  if (HttpContext.Current != null)  // this should alway be true
    url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();

  Dbg.WriteLine(String.Format("Request: {0} {1}", HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"], url));

  // integration calls measurement
  HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("wcfElapsed", new TimeSpan());

}

protected void Application_EndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string url = "";
  if (HttpContext.Current != null)  // this should alway be true
    url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();

  Dbg.WriteLine(String.Format("End request: {0} {1}", HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"], url));
}
```

This is our log file. Urls are omitted The 00013 column is thread id.

```
  14.12.10 21:41:25.042 00013 00000            Request: 172.23.26.41 
  14.12.10 21:41:25.068 00013 00000            End request: 172.23.26.41 
  14.12.10 21:41:25.212 00013 00000            Request: 172.23.26.41 
  14.12.10 21:41:25.223 00013 00000            End request: 172.23.26.41 
  14.12.10 21:41:30.974 00013 00000            End request: 172.23.26.88
```

You can see that there are two "End request" in the last two lines, but there is no (Begin) Request for the last log line.

Our Dbg.WriteLine uses System.Diagnostics trace listeners to ouput data to the file.

Environment: Windows Server 2008 R2, ASP.NET 3.5

This only happens when performin stress test. CPU utilization is around 60%, there are max 10 concurent requests executing.

Any ideas, what could be wrong?

**UPDATE:** I have found out that some other also did have similar problems (althoug in different configuration: http://forums.iis.net/t/1154954.aspx)
Matej

**UPDATE#2**: This night be related to fact, that Thread.GetHashCode() which is used to print out the thread identifier in our log fies could change. See [ASP.NET - Thread.GetHashCode() changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112333/asp-net-thread-gethashcode-changes)

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be down to debugging to file, not being able to handle all these events. Writing to file has its limitations.

I suggest using default debug trace which you can see in [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647).

Comment: We are ouputing the debug info both to the file and to the build-in .NET listener, that uses OutputDebugString Win32 API (which is intercepted by DebugView). I do not belive, that TextWriter skips some lines. <system.diagnostics> <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="0"> <listeners> <add name="dbgTrace" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\Logs\our.log" /> </listeners> </trace>

Comment: Great. So have you checked what you get in DebugView?

Comment: The DebugView should contains the same results as TextWriter. I can not use it during stress teste, because we log too much data.

Comment: @matra I think you still need to test it it contains the same to eliminate the threading issue with textwriterlistener.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not that the BeginRequest is not firing so much as there may be an unhandled unexception that is causing System.Diagnostics to crash without terminating the request.

The best way I could recommend to find the problem would be to install [IIS Debug Diagnostics](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=28bd5941-c458-46f1-b24d-f60151d875a3&displaylang=en) and run a crash or hang report. You won't like it much because the thing gathers tons and tons of data, but if there is some sort of thread crash/hang it will definitely catch it.

**Edit:**
While implementing a backup logging event directly to a custom Event Log in the system event log, we found that under heavy stress the requests for permission to access the log were causing latency (our guess was that after a certain number of requests the active directory connector was unable to respond in a timely fashion) and ultimately exceptions. This appeared to run on a separate thread which we could see dumping. W3wp.exe continued to function and the page fulfilled its response duties, but we found that of 3 events that should have been logged, the events getting logged were inconsistent. We also found that the event log itself would become busy and throw an exception. We found this one because from time to time this exception presented itself to the user interface instead of vanishing with the others. Our end solution was to use a local account to provide permission to the library to reduce the requests on the domain policy. This even cleared up the event log being busy symptom. At that point we were so happy it was gone we did not pursue it further.

Comment: It's hard to belive, that TextWriterTraceListener would swallow the exception. Windbg and other tools onfortunately can not be used through stress test, because they affect the test too much (they intercept OutputDebugString and write ouput to its own windows, which slows the stress test to the point of being useless). I Also examined TextWriterTraceListener with the Reflector and it does not swallow any exceptions. It just forwards the data to standard StreamWriter.

Comment: @matra - I don't have any forensic knowledge related to the threads, but I have seen threads under heavy load have exceptions on threads that get orphaned during the request cycle. I don't know that this is happening in your case but the symptom was similar, the request appears to complete fully, but for some reason pieces in the middle either did not execute at all or executed partially. In my case it always happened with unrelated dlls but never with a System dll.

Comment: @matra - also, it's not that the object or dll is "swallowing" the exception, it's just that if it's on an orphaned thread it has nowhere to report the exception. I actually just remembered, one of my problem children that caused this was System.Diagnostics.EventLog (so there WAS a system library). I will add an edit. There is too much for a comment.

Comment: Joel, thanks for the update. What do you mean by "pieces in the middle were not being executed" 1) some of the events were not raised or 2) i

Comment: Joel, thanks for the update. What do you mean by "pieces in the middle were not being executed" 1) some of the events were not raised or 2) the beginning and the end of a method executed, but not the middle part of the method. What do you mean by oprhaned thread 1) thread that was servising the HTTP request, but was interupted (in this case application_beginRequest should have been called and we should have a log entry in out text file) or 2) a background thread (yes, in this case it has nowhere to report the exception, but it is aslo unrelated to http request and BeginRequest)

Comment: @matra - We have some tasks in our Session_Start in the global.asax that perform in a certain order. Basically it checks some cookie variables, checks some application variables, attempts to generate a user object, then performs cookie updates and moves on. In both the Session_Start method and a couple of the library objects, messages into the log would be erratic. The only consistent thing is that if the log entries stopped for an object, they stopped for that object. The log for the cookie would work, then the user object would have the first log message work and no others ...

Comment: @matra - Then the next library object would perform its log. Sometimes that library WOULDN'T have performed it's log, but the user object performed all log writes. When we ran the debug diagnostics on it, we found that those particular calls appeared to be orphaned. By this I mean, the calls were made, no response received, yet the website just charged on with the next set of instructions. We were not spinning off BackgroundWorker processes either, yet parts of the thread just disappeared with no direct exception.