# ASP.NET - Thread.GetHashCode() changes

Tags: asp.net, multithreading

Is it possile that Thread.GetHashCode() changes during execution of a single request in ASP.NET

We use Thread.GetHashCode() when writing messages to log files (it's a old code from .NET 1.1. timerame - I know that .NET 3.0 supports Thread). When we analyze the logs it looks like, as if one thread started to process the requests and then the other one took over. and finished it.

**Update:** Environment: Windows server 2008 R2, (64 bit application pool), .NET 3.5, more than 30 simultaniously executing request, some of them can take up several minutes, high CPU usage, 8 GB phyisical memory,- 90-95% used, executed inside virtual machine (Vmware). We do not use asnyc HTTP handlers.

**Update #2**: We are also printing out AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId() in Application_Begin/EndRequest and this value also does *not* remains the same. GetHasCode changes()
Thanks,
  Matra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question. The answer is Yes - the thread can change during the executin of the request. See http://piers7.blogspot.com/2005/11/threadstatic-callcontext-and_02.html for details. Even though it's five ears old it seems to still be true ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It may happen if you are using asynchronous page processing or an async http handler (implementing IHttpAsyncHandler)

Comment: We are not using async handlers.